# Javascript accounts number of clicks then redirects to website

Tags: javascript

i need a way of redirecting to a website after several clicks, i havent found a way with onClick or addEventListener methods.

I was looking for a way of counting the clicks in the whole body of the website before launching an action.

Comment: Could you provide a clearer account of your problem and show what you have already in code? What is 'accounts number'? Which part of the code doesn't work?

Comment: The code does work, there's not too much documentation about how to include it through Google Web Designer, but is the same procedure as always, you just need to add the script inside the respective tags at the end and just add the as you normally would do it in an html document. Still the credit itself goes to DavidG, thank you man.

Comment: I'm sorry i meant a way of counting the clicks on the body of the html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very simply with `jQuery`. First create a variable to store the click count, then increment it every time something is clicked. After a number of clicks, navigate to your URL.

```js
var clickCount = 0;
$('body').click(function() {
  clickCount++;

  if (clickCount >= 3) {
    alert("Going to Google");

    //This line won't work because StackOverflow (quite rightly)
    //restricts it for security purposes
    document.location = "http://www.google.com";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
  Hello, click anywhere 3 times. There's no place like home...
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you!  i ran the code snippet and it worked once. But i'm getting there, the main issue for me, right now is trying to insert it inside google web designer for an ad. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Google Web Designer

Comment: Sorry, i meant, it's exactly what i needed, yet i'm having a hard time to include it into the ad created by googleadviewer.

Comment: The code does work, there's not too much documentation about how to include it through Google Web Designer, but is the same procedure as always, you just need to add the script inside the respective tags at the end and just add the as you normally would do it in an html document. Still the credit itself goes to DavidG, thank you man.